# Styling bootbox confirm dialog

Tags: jquery, bootbox

Bootbox Confirm display:

[image]

How to change the styling for bootbox confirm dialog?

```
$('#GoToLead').click(function (e) {
    var self = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (result) {
        if (result) {
            $('<input type="hidden" name="StartDate" />').val($('#StartDate').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
            $('<input type="hidden" name="EndDate" />').val($('#EndDate').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
            $('<input type="hidden" name="City" />').val($('#City').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
            $('<input type="hidden" name="AbbrName" />').val($('#AbbrName').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
            $('<input type="hidden" name="ZipCode" />').val($('#ZipCode').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
            $('<input type="hidden" name="FirstName" />').val($('#FirstName').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
            $('<input type="hidden" name="LastName" />').val($('#LastName').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
            $('<input type="hidden" name="EmailAddress" />').val($('#EmailAddress').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
            $('<input type="hidden" name="GroupNumber" />').val($('#GroupNumber').val()).appendTo('#theForm');
            self.unbind("click");
            self.get(0).click();
        }
    });
```

Comment: There's nothing in your post regarding CSS.. I'm not familiar with Bootbox, but it looks like it includes some styling. Have you included the CSS from Bootbox on your page?

Comment: bootbox dint had a css file :(

Comment: What CSS are you including in your project? There is styling here that doesn't come from Bootstrap, unless you're using some kind of theme.. If the modal is working then this is not a javascript problem, but a CSS problem.

Comment: modal is working fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add explanation of code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `className` option to apply a CSS selector, and then style accordingly. [Here's an example](https://tiesontrowbridge.com/bootbox/examples.html#bb-alert-dialog):

```
bootbox.alert({
    message: "This is an alert with an additional class!",
    className: 'bb-alternate-modal'
});
```

with:

```
.modal.bb-alternate-modal .modal-content {
    background: #555 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Styling bootbox confirm dialog**

we can customize bootbox using predefined **className**. We can also include form validation in the form of modal.
please follow these **links** to study more about bootbox:

http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootbox/

http://bootboxjs.com/v3.x/examples.html

Apart from them you can study these codes also

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

var Example = (function() {
"use strict";

var elem,
    hideHandler,
    that = {};

that.init = function(options) {
    elem = $(options.selector);
};

that.show = function(text) {
    clearTimeout(hideHandler);

    $("#result").html(text);
    $("#result").fadeIn();

    hideHandler = setTimeout(function() {
        that.hide();
    }, 4000);
};

that.hide = function() {
    $("#result").fadeOut();
};

return that;
}());




$('.alert').on('click',function()
{
    bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
    Example.show("Hello world callback");
});
    /*bootbox.alert(
            {
                title:"ashish bansal", //title which will be displayed on promt
                message:"<h2>Are you Agree?</h2>",//message on promt
                size:'large', //size of popup,default value is null and valid values are small and large only
                className: 'bb-alternate-modal',//css class to implement transformation effect 
                onEscape:true,//allow escape button to dismiss promt
                backdrop:true,// click on background dismiss alert
                callback:function()
                {
                    console.info("callback called successfully!");
                }
            });*/
});
$('.alert1').on('click',function()
{
    bootbox.confirm(
    {
            title:"bansal",
            message:"Are you Agree?",
            size:'large',
            buttons:
            {
                confirm:
                {
                    className:'btn-success',
                    label: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> YES'
                },
                cancel:
                {
                    className:'btn-danger',
                    label: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> NO'
                }
            },
            callback:function(result)
            {
                console.info("confirm promt called successfully with result:"+result);
            },
            //closeButton:false// hide close button
            //animate:false // by default it is true.used to animte alert in out style
    });
 });
 $('.alert2').on('click',function()
{
    bootbox.prompt(
    {
            title:"Select your favourite items",
            message:"Welcome to world of promt messages",
            size:'large',
            inputType:'checkbox',
            inputOptions:[{
                text:'Shoes',
                value:'1'
            },
            {
                text:'Bike',
                value:'2'
            },
            {
                text:'Rose',
                value:'3'
            }],
            inputType:'email',
            inputType:'number',
            inputType:'select',
            inputOptions:[{
                text:'Shoes',
                value:'1'
            },
            {
                text:'Bike',onEscape:true,//allow escape button to dismiss promt
                backdrop:true,// click on background dismiss alert
                value:'2'
            },
            {
                text:'Rose',
                value:'3'
            }],
            //inputType:'date',
            callback:function(result)
            {
                Example.show("confirm promt called successfully with result:"+result);
            }
    });
 }); 
 $('.alert3').on('click',function()
 {
     bootbox.dialog(
     { 
        message: '<div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> Loading...</div>',
        onEscape:true,//allow escape button to dismiss promt
        backdrop:true// click on background dismiss alert
     }); 
 });
 $('.alert4').on('click',function()
 {
     var dialog = bootbox.dialog(
     {
        title: 'A custom dialog with init',
        message: '<p><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> Loading...</p>',
        onEscape:true,//allow escape button to dismiss promt
        backdrop:true// click on background dismiss alert
     });
    dialog.init(function()
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            dialog.find('.bootbox-body').html('I was loaded after the dialog was shown!');
        }, 3000);
    });
 });
 });
```